# Accessing variable from inner class using alert dialog

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an Android Java app for converting different wind speeds and i have an if statement set up based on conversion required. I'm using an intent to transfer to the second activity after an alertdialog has confirmed the users choice. Problem is, the intent variable i isn't being accessed while in the inner class and it "cannot find symbol method onclicklistener. Any ideas?

```
Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), DisplayCalculationActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("speedValue",speed);
        i.putExtra("measurement", measurement);

        AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        dialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to convert\n " + speed + "from " + measurement);
        dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Convert",
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                })
        );

        dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "No",
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v)  {

                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
        );


        dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "Cancel",
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
        );


    }
```

Comment: declare `Intent i` as `final`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare Intent as final and also correct your usage of the OnClickListener.

e.g

```
dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Convert", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                DisplayCalculationActivity.this.startActivity(i);
            }
        }
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `i` as final.